# Javascript string decoding logic translated to Python

Tags: javascript, python, js2py

The following Javascript code will decode string `91ebf9e9f7a8a2a1a5d1a0a3a7bff2fefc`
into an intelligible value:

```
!function() {
    "use strict";
    function e(e) {
        try {
            if ("undefined" == typeof console)
                return;
            "error"in console ? console.error(e) : console.log(e)
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    function t(e) {
        return d.innerHTML = '<a href="' + e.replace(/"/g, "&quot;") + '"></a>',
        d.childNodes[0].getAttribute("href") || ""
    }
    function r(e, t) {
        var r = e.substr(t, 2);
        return parseInt(r, 16)
    }
    function n(n, c) {
        for (var o = "", a = r(n, c), i = c + 2; i < n.length; i += 2) {
            var l = r(n, i) ^ a;
            o += String.fromCharCode(l)
        }
        try {
            o = decodeURIComponent(escape(o))
        } catch (u) {
            e(u)
        }
        return t(o)
    }
    function c(t) {
        for (var r = t.querySelectorAll("a"), c = 0; c < r.length; c++)
            try {
                var o = r[c]
                  , a = o.href.indexOf(l);
                a > -1 && (o.href = "mailto:" + n(o.href, a + l.length))
            } catch (i) {
                e(i)
            }
    }
    function o(t) {
        for (var r = t.querySelectorAll(u), c = 0; c < r.length; c++)
            try {
                var o = r[c]
                  , a = o.parentNode
                  , i = o.getAttribute(f);
                if (i) {
                    var l = n(i, 0)
                      , d = document.createTextNode(l);
                    a.replaceChild(d, o)
                }
            } catch (h) {
                e(h)
            }
    }
    function a(t) {
        for (var r = t.querySelectorAll("template"), n = 0; n < r.length; n++)
            try {
                i(r[n].content)
            } catch (c) {
                e(c)
            }
    }
    function i(t) {
        try {
            c(t),
            o(t),
            a(t)
        } catch (r) {
            e(r)
        }
    }
    var l = "/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#"
      , u = ".__cf_email__"
      , f = "data-cfemail"
      , d = document.createElement("div");
    i(document),
    function() {
        var e = document.currentScript || document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e)
    }()
}();
```

Can anyone explain the actual logic of it, to be able to write it into Python? Or come up with an `JS2PY` solution of running the code against python-selected values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) module to *rewrite* automatically the Js code to Python:

```py
import js2py

js_script = """\
  function decode(email) {
      function r(e, t) {
        var r = e.substr(t, 2);
        return parseInt(r, 16);
      }

      function n(n, c) {
        for (var o = "", a = r(n, c), i = c + 2; i < n.length; i += 2) {
          var l = r(n, i) ^ a;
          o += String.fromCharCode(l);
        }
        return o;
      }

    var l = "/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#";
    return n(email, email.indexOf(l) + l.length);
  }
"""

decoder = js2py.eval_js(js_script)
email = decoder(
    "https://journals.sagepub.com/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#7c0614041a454f4c483c4d4e4a521f1311431f1f414d454c454c494b4a4d3c0d0d521f1311"
)
print(email)
```

Prints your email.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus As a side-note: It will be better to rewrite the Js to python, the functions aren't so long and seem simple enough (looking at it it's XORing the characters). If somebody has time and rewrites it, I'll upvote it :)